# How can I use auth0 to register users and protect my API, but get the user_id

Tags: auth0

I am using auth0 to register users on my application, and hope to also use their api auth.

However, I have some endpoints like `POST /api/v1/events` which requires a authenticated user.

In the application side, each `event` has a `createdByUserID` which is the user id of the requestor.  I would like to get the `userID` from each request that comes in.

How can I accomplish this?  I'm trying to follow their docs but I am having a pretty hard time.

Comment: You would send the Auth0 access token JWT to your endpoint, which can then decode the JWT and extract the `sub` claim from the token payload to identify the requesting user. Or is your question regarding how to even get the access token in the first place?

Comment: My question is how to store the user that I authenticated in my database.  If I sign up with email/pass, my app's signup isn't done yet because I need name and address.  The auth0 will make a new user, but for my app I still haven't created the user.  At what point of the login process do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rule in Auth0 to call your application when a user is registered. See [this forum post](https://community.auth0.com/t/configure-implement-callback-after-user-registration/11895/3). You can access details about the newly registered user in your rule, to extract data to pass to your application - see the [Auth0 doc](https://auth0.com/docs/rules/references/user-object).